# Text animation not working on iOS browsers

Tags: javascript, html, ios

Text animation not working on iOS browsers. I have written this simple code for text animation which working on android browsers but not on iOS.

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h2{
font-size: 45px;
}
span:before {
content:'';
animation-name: example;
animation-duration: 8s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes example {
0%{
content:'mirror';
}
40%{
content:'catalyst';
}
80%{
content:'disruptor';
}
100%{
content:'partner';
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div><h2> I am your <span></span>.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome, Edge, Mozilla and Safari use different rendering engines, to render graphics, animations etc. The problems that is arising in your case is that you aren't using Safari's rendering engine, webkit. Instead of

```
animation-name: example;
animation-duration: 8s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

Do

```
-webkit-animation-name: example;
-webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

Note: Just a suggestion, instead of using three lines of code to declare animations, you should preferably use the animation shorthand property. If you are interested in CSS animations, you can visit my [blog](https://originalcodingcult.blogspot.com/).

Happy Coding!!

Comment: If this solved your problem you can accept this as the answer.